# Handling DateTime precision > 6 in Elixir

Tags: datetime, elixir, precision

I have this function in my code:

```
  defp to_date({year, month, day}), do: NaiveDateTime.from_erl!({{year, month, day}, {0, 0, 0}}, {0, 6}) |> NaiveDateTime.to_string()
  defp to_date({{year, month, day}, {hour, min, sec, msec}}) when msec < 1000000,
    do: NaiveDateTime.from_erl!({{year, month, day}, {hour, min, sec}}, {msec, 6}) |> NaiveDateTime.to_string()

  defp to_date(x), do: x
```

How would you handle cases when `msec > 6-digits`.

Pulling data from a SQLServer `datetime2(7)` with the Tds library works just fine:

```
iex(45)> r = Tds.Connection.query(:RMASDB, "select * from users where user_id = 1" , [])
{:ok,
 %Tds.Result{columns: ["user_id", "name", "email", "mobiles", "password", "roles", "active", "reset_required", "last_login", "has_picture", "last_modified", "last_modified_by"], command: nil, num_rows: 1,
  rows: [[1, "Charles Okwuagwu", "charleso@mydomain.com", "mobile1, mobile2", "/eNvuOyr5N6HxgYdz3fK7A==|QHx/sOa3Se0C3ZeLSNtT97SCsuWL11SJeLykms7faGY=", "Administrator", true, false,
    {{2017, 11, 30}, {18, 37, 26, 2690120}}, true, {{2017, 11, 30}, {0, 0, 0, 0}}, 1]]}}
```

but processing the dates with my code below throws this exception:

```
iex(46)> DB.get(DB.Users, "select * from users where user_id = 1")                      
** (ArgumentError) cannot convert {{2017, 11, 30}, {18, 37, 26}} to naive datetime, reason: :invalid_time
    (elixir) lib/calendar/naive_datetime.ex:549: NaiveDateTime.from_erl!/2
    (rmas) lib/db.ex:34: DB.to_date/1
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1270: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1270: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
    (rmas) lib/db.ex:26: anonymous fn/3 in DB._objects/3
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1270: Enum."-map/2-lists^map/1-0-"/2
    (rmas) lib/db.ex:17: DB.get/3
```

The source data-value is: `{{2017, 11, 30}, {18, 37, 26, 2690120}}`

Comment: Your exception shows a time tuple with 3 elements, while your source data-value says it's 4 elements. What's the correct one?

Comment: @JonasDellinger the source value is 4 elements, its an erlang time-format

Comment: Elixir's error reporting shows just 3 elements for some reason

Comment: @JonasDellinger i've updated the question with the full error

Comment: Why is microseconds more than 6 digits anyway? Looks like an error in the library you're using. And what would you like to do with a time with > 1e6 microseconds? add the extra to the seconds field?

Comment: @Dogbert i'm simply trying to read data from a sql server datetime2(7) column

Comment: some one on elixirforum sugested a solution to this https://elixirforum.com/t/handling-datetime-precision-6/10578/3?u=charleso

Comment: Oh I just saw your second comment after posting my answer (I only received notification for the first one since you didn't tag me in the second). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `datetime2(7)` field stores with a precision of one-tenth of a microsecond. A `NaiveDateTime` only supports a precision of microseconds so you can divide the value by 10 to get the microseconds and use that:

```
defp to_date({{year, month, day}, {hour, min, sec, seven}}),
  do: NaiveDateTime.from_erl!({{year, month, day}, {hour, min, sec}}, {div(seven, 10), 6}) |> NaiveDateTime.to_string()
```

We divide using `div` instead of `/` so that the result is an integer and not a float.

Comment: any reason why the core team didn't design the NaiveDateTime.from_erl! to handle more than `{0..999999, 0..6}`? considering that the VM supports :nanoseconds?